# How can I prevent full page zoom on mousewheel event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, zooming, mousewheel, trackpad

I want to be able to use the trackpad and the `wheel` event to update the scale of a DOM element. It works like expected however on several browsers it also perform a full page zoom.

I want to keep my scale update but I want to prevent the full page zoom.

I've read that adding `e.preventDefault` in the wheel event would prevent that. I had it but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/ChucKN0risK/full/JqwrVe

Comment: Have you seen this article: https://medium.com/@auchenberg/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript-a2505babb10e?

Comment: Yes I did and I even test the provided demo. However the zoom also triggers a full page zoom. The article comments advise to use `e.preventDefault();` which doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks to @Mteuahasan answer I updated the code provided by the OP so that it prevents a full page zoom: https://codepen.io/ChucKN0risK/pen/YbbjNL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Event binded at document level (window.document, window.document.body, or window) are treated as passive and can't be prevented. You should specify that the event is not passive with `{ passive: false }` as third parameter of your `addEventListener` function. See [this link](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312) for more info.

In your case :

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        var s = Math.exp(-e.deltaY / 100);
        scale *= s;
    } else {
        var direction = 1; //natural.checked ? -1 : 1;
        tx += e.deltaX * direction;
        ty += e.deltaY * direction;
    }
    var transform = 'translate(' + tx + 'px, ' + ty + 'px) scale(' + scale + ')';
    box.style.webkitTransform = transform;
    box.style.transform = transform;
}, {
    passive: false // Add this
});
```

Moreover it won't work on codepen due to the use of the iframe as event is binded on the iframe and not on the codepen page itself.

Comment: I would also add that the `e.stopPropagation()` isn't needed to prevent the full page zoom ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
e.preventDefault();  e.stopPropagation();
```

Try using both of these

Comment: You need to use both together